# How to create an image that is black on one side, and white on the other side, using Gimp?

Tags: gimp, images, workflow

I need a way to create a new image in Gimp which is completely black on one side, and completely white on the other. I've tried color to alpha but that did not seem to yield the correct results. I'm just looking for a workflow. I suspect it has something to do with adding new layers. Any suggestions?

Context:
I'm trying to generate images similar to the MNIST dataset. The processed images show only black and white values. I'm trying to figure out why there are no gray pixels in my finished images. For debugging, I want to create an image which is black on one side, white on the other side. I will then downscale it to 3x3, which will result in the middle of the image having a gray value.
I'm using area interpolation as my method of resizing the image.

The goal is to make the resultant image look as close as possible to these images: https://knowyourdata-tfds.withgoogle.com/#tab=STATS&dataset=mnist. Right now my images have no gray values, only black and white pixels.

The end goal is secondary for now, I'm just looking for a way to create an image that has black pixels on one side and white on the other side. I mentioned Color By ALpha because that is one of the things that came up when I was googling how to do this. The area interpolation method should create antialiasing and introduce gray values, but it doesn't.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please show an example of what you are trying  to achieve, or what has failed.  It's hard to answer this question with so few details. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update, but we need to see the images.

Comment: Open a new image with white background. Select half.. Fill with black... save.. I'm not a GIMP user so I can't provide specific tool/features to use, but it seems really straight-forward. It doesn't sound as if there are any images @BillyKerr - At least how I read this.

Comment: @Scott - I also read it that way at first, but then the OP mentioned using color to alpha. So It may or may not be as simple as we think, because colour to alpha is a method for  removing a background. I'm at a loss TBH.  Googling "MNIST dataset" didn't help. All I found is that it has something to do with machine learning/AI.

Comment: As I read.. the desire is to downsample an image with hard, defined back/white edge so that the downsampling creates anti-aliasing. Then *that* downsampled image will be used as reference for *other* unrelated images. Basically just [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJv1k.png) so it can then be downsized -- But maybe I read it wrong. @jwalantbhatt please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, currently this reads like an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I don't really disagree `:)`

Comment: You are correct @BillyKerr, it is an XY problem right now. I'm using OpenCV with inter_area as my interpolation method. This should create AA and introduce gray pixels, but it doesn't. WOuld it help if I uploaded the source code for my image processing python file in the question?

Comment: Most here are designers @Jwalant... not python writers. You may get lucky though.

Comment: @jwalantbhatt - I don't know what OpenCV is either. No, code really won't help you much here, and coding is generally off-topic here anyway.  I think perhaps you might be better asking this on Computer Graphics Stack Exchange.   This site is for graphic design only. GIMP is only a raster image editor. It might not be capable of doing what you want, but I can't even tell what you want. Sorry.

Comment: I appreciate the help @BillyKerr and Scott. Thanks.

Comment: @jwalantbhatt - you're welcome. Good luck, hope you find a solution!

Comment: @jwalantbhatt - just read your recent update and looked at the link. Are you trying to simulate Anti-aliasing?  Not sure if it will work for you, but GIMP has a Gaussian Blur filter. Maybe a 0.5px blur might do it?

Comment: [see example here](https://imgur.com/o1clIQu)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image with black on one side, white on the other, and  a gray transition in between, use the blend tool with a black to white gradient (or the `FG to BG (RGB)` gradient with the default black/white foreground/background colors. You can use [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) if you wan to accurately position the transition (and depress the Ctrl key while you drag, to constrain the gradient to be exactly horizontal). It looks like this:

[image]

- Set up guides of needed (this makes the pointer "snap" to them when you are near)➊
- Set the Tool to the adequate gradient➋
- Shape should be `Linear`➌
- No `Repeat`➍
- You may want to turn off dithering (kept enabled here)➎
- Click on the first guide to start the tool➏
- Depress `Ctrl` and drag to the other guide➐
- If necessary you can click on the midpoint and move it to change how the gradient evolves.➑